# Ember: Error while processing route. Can't hit API

Tags: ember.js

This code works (hardcoded):

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
    model() {
        let stars = [
            {
                key: "johnlennon",
                logoUrl: "https://www.images.com/johnl.png",
                name: "John Lennon",
                alive: false
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When I do this, it doesn't (from API):

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';
import config from '../../../../../config/environment';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
    model() {
        const token = this.get('session.data.authenticated.token');
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            stars: Ember.$.getJSON(Ember.$.getJSON(`${config.APP.starsAPI}/api/stars?authorizationToken=${token}`))
        });
    }
});
```

The error I receive:

> jquery.js:9175 GET
>   http://localhost:4242/stars/948/connect/[object%20Object] 404 (Not
>   Found)
>
> ember.debug.js:30291 Error while processing route:
>   stars.show.connect.stars.index

As you may have guessed, I need it to work from API. Why is that giving me the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after this change:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';
import config from '../../../../../config/environment';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
    model() {
        const token = this.get('session.data.authenticated.token');
        return Ember.$.getJSON(`${config.APP.starsApi}/api/stars?authorizationToken=${token}`).then(function(retVal){
            return retVal;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you had chained `Ember.$.getJSON() methods.

```
return Ember.$.getJSON(`${config.APP.starsApi}/api/stars?authorizationToken=${token}`).then(function(retVal){
    return retVal;
});
```

This should work fine